# Using a filter for options when using ngOptions

Tags: angularjs

When I was using the `ngRepeat` attribute on `options` I could filter the labels using `myFilter` by doing something like this:

```
<select ng-model="model">
    <option ng-repeat="option in myOptions" value="option.id">
        {{option.name | myFilter}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Since recently have switched to using the `ngOptions` directive for displaying options in a `select` element using Angularjs. So my `select` element code looks something along the lines of this now:

```
<select ng-model="model"
    ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in myOptions">
</select>
```

But now I don't know what is Angular's attribute where I can define to filter the labels of the `options` (if such even exists). So what I want is, using the second code, to run the labels for the `options` through the `myFilter` filter.

Comment: The below answers are working good for you.... luckyyyyyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working exemple from my code :

```
<select ng-options="status.displayName | translate for status in vm.admissionstatusSelection"> 
</select>
```

Should work for you the same way like this :

```
<select ng-model="model"
ng-options="option.id as option.name | myFilter for option in myOptions">
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use filter like this

```
<select ng-model="create_price" ng-options="obj as (obj | filter) for obj in objectList"> 

</select>
```